# How to copy a list to another variable and leave this variable immutable?

Tags: python, list, copy, slice, immutablelist

I've maid an algorithm that reverse the diagonals of an array. I'm trying to copy the list `a` to `b` immutable.

I tried to use "slices" (`b = a[:]`), list comprehension and `b = a.copy()` but the only one that worked was `b = copy.deepcopy(a)`. Are there other ways to get the copy?

```py
import copy
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
d = b
c = []

h = len(a[0])-1
x_ptrocar = []

for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if i == h:
        break
    else:
        x_ptrocar.extend([[i,i,h,h],[i,h,h,i],[h,h,i,i],[h,i,i,h]])
        h -=1
for l in range(len(x_ptrocar)):
    for m in range(0,4):
        y_original = x_ptrocar[l][3]
        y_ptrocar = x_ptrocar[l][1]
        x_original = x_ptrocar[l][2]
        x_ptrocarr = x_ptrocar[l][0]
        a[x_original][y_original]=b[x_ptrocarr][y_ptrocar]
print(a)
```

I expect the output of `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` to be `[[9,2,7], [4,5,6],[3,8,1]]`, and it's working for `copy.deepcopy`, but not for any other method I can find.

Comment: you don't actually want an immutable list, you just want to actually create copies of your list, since your algorithm relies on mutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy.deepcopy` is overkill for this, pulling in a module and adding function overhead. Since you have a list of lists, making a copy of the outer list with `b = a[:]` isn't sufficient because the inner lists in both `a` and `b` point to identical objects.

You can use a list comprehension as follows:

```
b = [x[:] for x in a]
```

This takes a slice of each list in `a`, creating a new copy of each sublist without aliasing.

---

Incidentally, the logic can be simplified somewhat--walk towards the center of the matrix, swapping the top-left/bottom-right and top-right/bottom-left cells along the way:

```
def reverse_diagonals(m):
    m = [x[:] for x in m]

    for i in range(len(m) // 2):
        m[i][i], m[-i-1][-i-1] = m[-i-1][-i-1], m[i][i]
        m[i][-i-1], m[-i-1][i] = m[-i-1][i], m[i][-i-1]

    return m
```

This assumes a nxn matrix.